# import a modal and a backdrop in the project, but it doesn't seem to be recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to import a modal and a backdrop in the project, but it doesn't seem to be recognized

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Backdrop from "./Backdrop";

function Todo(props) {
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function DeleteHandeler() {
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.text}</h2>
      <div className="actions">
        <button className="btn" onClick={DeleteHandeler}>
          delete
        </button>
      </div>
      {modalIsOpen && <Modal />}
      {modalIsOpen && <Backdrop />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

I want to see that even though I have followed all the steps, it still doesn't recognize it

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Does anything change in the DOM when you try to open your modal?

Comment: Without seeing your folder structure and other files code it is hard to find the source of the error.

Comment: The required files are in GitHub https://github.com/AmirNulll/react-course

Answer (score 0):

The paths for the `Modal` and `Backdrop` components in the `App` are not specified. Error disappeared for me when I registered the paths of the Modal and Backdrop components in the App component.

App.js

```
import Todo from "./Components/Todo";
import Modal from "./Components/Modal";
import Backdrop from "./Components/Backdrop";


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My todo</h1>

      <Todo text="Hello" />
      <Todo text="World" />
      <Modal />
      <Backdrop />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```